# Is there a way to capture the exit code of the child command when run through strace?

Tags: perl, phpunit, strace

I'm trying to trace the files involved in running a unit test by using strace. Is there a way I can capture the exitcode of the test run while I do this?

```
@cmd="php -d auto_prepend_file=auto_prepend_for_tests.php /data/tests/sdk/bin/phpunit.phar --configuration /data/tests/conf/database.xml
 my_test.php"
open(IN, "-|", "strace -ff $pid -e trace=file @cmd 2>&1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Strace will exit with the same exit code as the traced program. So far so good.

The open looks a bit perlish, is that perl we are talking about?
Then this bit from `perldoc -f open` applies:

> Closing any piped filehandle causes the parent process to wait for the
>   child to finish, then returns the status value in $? and
>   "${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}".

So, yes, you can get the code by calling `close IN` and looking at the value in $?.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, that is perl script. I'm trying to get all the files loaded while running a phpunit test through this script. I see that $? always returns an `exitcode 0` when I know the test returns an `exitcode 139`.
Here's what I tried:
```
open(IN, "-|", "strace -ff $pid -e trace=file @cmd 2>&1") || die;
# print $?;
close(IN) ? print "exitcode is $?" : die();
print $?;
print "${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}";
print $CHILD_ERROR;
```

Comment: @Prathyusha If you run phpunit without strace, does it actually return 139? I see some bug reports where they always returned 0: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1659

Comment: I'm positive. Ran the command separately on the console and saw it returned 139. Also, tried a different test which returns exitcode 1. Still seeing `exitcode 0` in the perl script.

For ref:
I'm making use of similar code in https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/blob/master/tracefile/tracefile

Comment: @Prathyusha Maybe you could look for messages like `[pid 12345] +++ exited with 42 +++` in the output

Comment: Git the solution. I was looking for the exitcode at the wrong place. Here's what I've done.

```open(IN, "-|", "strace -ff $pid -e trace=file @cmd 2>&1") || die;
while(<IN>) {
    // some logic
}
close(IN);
print "exitcode=" . ($? >> 8);```